# no mousewheel but do need touchpad support for swiperjs

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Swiperjs is awesome but how do I enable two finger swiping(touchpad) without turning on mousewheel control? Preferably only horizontal.

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for the same answer. Trackpad is not a unique DOM event if I understand correctly. However

```
const mySwiperConfig = {
    mousewheel: {
        forceToAxis: true,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

worked well enough for me. This prohibits the swiper from picking up scrolling up and down on the page and translating it horizontally thru the slides. With this config only horizontal trackpad scroll activates the slider.

source:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4442#issuecomment-822256851